# How to handle different types of objects?

Tags: php

I've discovering an issue in my PHP code. I'm used to write PHP code with Objects and Managers. For example: **Photo** is an object and **PhotoManager** is a managers. I also have a **User** object and a **UserManager**.

See the following bit of code:

```
<?php

class Photo
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $user;

    public function __construct($id, $name, User $user)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}

?>

<?php

class User
{
    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function __construct($id, $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

?>

<?php

class PhotoManager
{
    public function loadAll()
    {
        // load all photos (array with objects)
    }

    public function loadById($id)
    {
        // return a single photo (object)
    }
}

?>

<?php

class UserManager
{
    public function loadAll()
    {
        // load all users (array with objects)
    }

    public function loadById($id)
    {
        // return a single user (object)
    }
}

?>
```

This works fine. Please not that in my current code the Managers are much bigger with all kinds of functionality.

I use the managers like this:

```
<?php

$userManager = new UserManager();
$photoManager = new PhotoManager();

?>
```

The problem is that I want to add a **User** object into a **Photo** object. So what is the way to go with using the **UserManager** in the **PhotoManager**?? Because I want to access the **loadById** function from the **UserManager** when I'm loading the **User** for the **Photo** object.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify PhotoManager to load UserManager as a property:

```
class PhotoManager
{
    private $userManager;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->userManager = new UserManager();
    }

    public function loadAll()
    ....
```

After making this change, you can access the UserManager's `loadById()` via `$this->userManager->loadById()`.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the MVP design, I don't really recommend that, but if you really have to, you could make Photo and User implement a common interface, or have a userManager inside the photo manager and viceversa